# Python 3.11 declare variable typing without assigning value

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.11

I've been wondering what's the most pythonic way and also most readable way to **declare a variable's type without directly assigning a value** in **Python 3.11**

Given a class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self.value: str = value
```

I could declare the variable without assigning a value:

```
def test():
    variable: MyClass
    if True:
        variable = MyClass(value="value")
    else:
        variable = MyClass(value="otherValue")
```

That would work but the variable is non existant when trying to use it so it's there just for readability.

I could use Optional

```
def test():
    variable: Optional[MyClass] = None
    if True:
        variable = MyClass(value="value")
    else:
        variable = MyClass(value="otherValue")
    assert isinstance(variable, MyClass)
```

Or I could type it on first use

```
def test():
    if True:
        variable: MyClass = MyClass(value="value")
    else:
        variable = MyClass(value="otherValue")
```

I couldn't find anything in [Peps](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), chatGpt4 is contradicting itself, and google sends me to 2015 GitHub's questions.
The tool MyPy seems to be fine with the three of them, but I wonder, is there a "correct" way ?

Thank you!

Comment: "chatGpt4 is contradicting itself"—of course it is. It just dumps out words that kinda sorta make sense, which means it's frequently wrong. Don't trust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, by parsing Pep again here's what I found:

> In stubs it may be useful to declare the existence of a variable
> without giving it an initial value. This can be done using PEP 526
> variable annotation syntax:
>
> ```
> from typing import IO
>
> stream: IO[str]
> ```
>
> The above syntax is acceptable in stubs for all versions of Python.
> However, in non-stub code for versions of Python 3.5 and earlier there
> is a special case:
>
> ```
> from typing import IO
>
> stream = None  # type: IO[str]
> ```
>
> Type checkers should not complain about this (despite the value None
> not matching the given type), nor should they change the inferred type
> to Optional[...] (despite the rule that does this for annotated
> arguments with a default value of None). The assumption here is that
> other code will ensure that the variable is given a value of the
> proper type, and all uses can assume that the variable has the given
> type.

So the "correct" way seems to be

```
def test():
    variable = None  # type: MyClass
    if True:
        variable = MyClass(value="value")
    else:
        variable = MyClass(value="otherValue")
```

So it seems we're still using comments as a way of typing which I'm personally not a big fan of.

Edit: As noted by InSync in the comment, I did not read correctly, the comment is needed for python 3.5 and **earlier**. So this version seems to be the one recommended

```
from typing import IO

stream: IO[str]
```

Comment: "*So it seems we're still using comments as a way of typing*": You won't need `type` comments (except for, possibly, `type: ignore`) on Python 3.6 and above. This is exlicitly noted in the part you quoted.

Comment: And given that Python 3.5 has out of support for over 3 years, you can reasonably ignore it in answers written in 2024.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring without assignment until later in the function:

```
variable: MyClass
```

Using Optional with None assignment:

```
variable: Optional[MyClass] = None
```

Type it on first use:

```
variable: MyClass = MyClass(a="value")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way. As far as I know, these three ways all work, albeit not the same.

Personally, I think the first way is the best of the three, since it follows the classic "declare your variables on the top" principle, allows for symmetric-looking branches and doesn't require an initial, unnecessary value.

On the other hand, that is not the most Pythonic way I could think of. If your conditional branches are simple enough, you can just leave out the type hint altogether and let the type checker infer:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=e8f2161aef3ad264934c047a5e4afbba), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUBcBYAUNH0AmApgGbQD6pAlgHYUAu5AFBASEQDTQBuYIArgamgRaAJwCUGbLmnNWAOm58BQ0dAC8XHvyxZCJWgWEMx0ALQA%2BaADkA9lQFZpFEgBUR-SdOncRFMACMQAnU4JBQIBkV%2BNQAiKIIYsUdcFmZPLxwfP0DgjQRkSAj42JtaAAsCEQA1LQSkzGScEQJOAh5SWngABwJIsF8AoJNoAGJoAFtu%2BGgAMmgu%2BF8AczLadUt88KwgA))</sub>

```py
def test():
  if True:
    variable = MyClass(value="value")
  else:
    variable = MyClass(value="otherValue")

  reveal_type(variable)  # mypy & pyright => MyClass
```